# Installing (Laravel) Dusk on Lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen, laravel-dusk

I am building a self-consuming Lumen API that has a single Lumen view (which serves the HTML to which the React app is appended).

I was able to install Dusk with 
`composer require --dev laravel/dusk` 
which seemed successful.

However, when I run 
`php artisan dusk:install` 
I get 
`There are no commands defined in the "dusk" namespace.`

I know Lumen has a stripped-down php artisan. But, wondering if I can  add the commands to the "dusk" namespace, or if anyone has successfully used Dusk with Lumen.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow -- could you share your AppServiceProvider?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Jared's answer,

I found I had to manually register Dusk's service provider before I could run `php artisan dusk:install`. The current Laravel documentation doesn't mention registering it, but it seems like it might have to be done for Lumen.

So all I had to do was add

```
if (app()->environment('local')) {
    $app->register(Laravel\Dusk\DuskServiceProvider::class);
}
```

to `/bootstrap/app.php` below the `Register Service Providers` comment.

As Jared mentions, you don't want it to register in production environments so I stuck it in a conditional.

Once added, I was able to run `php artisan dusk:install` and got `Dusk scaffolding installed successfully.`

Answer (score 3):

Be sure you have the `.env` file setup correctly.
The `APP_ENV` should be set to `local` or `testing` for dusk to work.

Also check if it's was correctly installed by checking the Register Service Providers in your `bootstrap/app.php` file. Dusk should be listed there.

If you are manually registering Dusk's service provider, you should never register it in your production environment, as doing so could lead to arbitrary users being able to authenticate with your application.

Comment: Thanks Jared, you led me to the solution which I'll post below.